# How to set Spring active profile while running in WebLogic?

Tags: weblogic, profile

I want to set spring active profile in weblogic settings.
I have three properties in src/main/resources. For examp : application-dev.properties , application-qa.properties , application-test.properties.

I dont want to keep spring.profiles.active property in my application.properties file. As I have to change it every time whenever I want to deploy in different server.

I want to active the profile in weblogic (my deploying server for application). Whats is the way and how to fetch the value in springboot application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pass the profile as java argument -Dspring.profiles.active=dev

Comment: Thanks. after setting -Dspring.profiles.active in weblogic classpath how to get the value in java app? through @value?

Comment: under normal circumstances you would not have to do that, but if you must hen you can use @value more details at https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/23/spring-tips-configuration

Answer (score 0):

A secure way to set profiles in springboot applications is to set environment variables with it. In general, it is a good approach, so you can define it differently for each one of your environments (dev, qa and prod).

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620163/best-way-to-set-environmental-variables-in-weblogic-startup) discussion, which explains specifically about Weblogic. In java, you need the SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE environment variable set.